# opening and reading Excel file in PHP

Tags: phpexcel

I am a new bie to PhP , also i am new into the corporate world, I have been given an assignment by my seniors .Can please any one help me with the scripting of opening and reading an excel file in PHP. I have read a lot for it over google, but still nothing really is helping me.

Looking for positive replies.

Answer (score 1):

I've used http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/ before and would recommend it, it's quite simple and intuitive.

Comment: Thanx for your reply, but in actual i need a PHP script thru which an excel file can be creatd dynamically and then i can perform reading and writing operations simultaneously on the same.. Waiting for ur reply

Answer (score 1):

PHPExcel is what I would use. It is a bit of a pig but maybe they were just trying to conform to Microsoft standards. ;) I have had issues with extremely large tables of data. Aside from using the native tools you can also save file to excel xml. Much faster and works on anything excel 2003 and up (haven't tried on 2011 but should work.) As a last resort if you are parsing large amounts of data a standard csv is easy to do.

Comment: Thanx Alan for ur reply, but in actual i need a PHP script thru which an excel file can be creatd dynamically and then i can perform reading and writing operations simultaneously on the same.. Waiting for ur reply

Comment: And i tried to work with PhP excel too, but i am not able to configure the same with the coding.PLease help me out